# Automatically accessing Truecrypt/Keepass etc. using Windows 7 password

Tags: c#, security, authentication, keylogger

I basically want to automatically mount a (non-system) Truecrypt volume or start Keypass just protected with a single (secure) password, the one windows 7 use for default authentification.
I'm using C#.

1. Is there anyway to get this password when already being logged in?
2. Or anyway to get this password while I'm actually typing it during the login process.

For 1. I couldn't find anything (the password is not stored anywhere, just a hash of the password is stored)

For 2. I already tryed some things. I got a program to execute before a user logs on using 
`GPEDIT.MSC` **Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts -> StartUp**.
Then I tryed to get the password using global key hooks (tryed `GetAsyncKeyState` and `SetWindowsHookEx`). Both work well when I try to capture keys when I'm already logged in, but not during the login process.

But I found a keylogging software (Elite Keylogger) which is actually able to get the password that way (when logging in). (I tryed the trial version in VMWare). The other things if tryed in VM Ware and also on a real machine.

Thank you for any help or tips.

Comment: You could use an EFS- or BitLocker-encrypted keyfile for Truecrypt. It will get unlogged as soon as you log in.

Comment: Another idea would be to implement a custom credential provider to get the password (not sure if this is possible). Otherwise you'd have to get into some dark magic (custom keyboard driver etc.) to get hold of the password.

Comment: Bitlocker basically IS an auto-mounting truecrypt volume.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing something similar with batch scripting in order to automatically mount a Truecrypt (or Veracrypt if you prefer) volume upon Windows login with Windows 10.  I use a KeePass file setup to use Windows Authentication to securely house the encrypted volume password.

Here's the process:
1) Create your truecrypt or veracrypt non-system volume
2) Create a KeyPass file to hold an entry containing the password to the encrypted volume. Setup the KeyPass file to use windows authentication under the login you will use when you want the drive to automatically mount.
3) Use a batch script like the one below to open the encrypted volume.  By housing the password in the KeyPass file with windows authentication you prevent exposing the password in plain-text in the batch file.  You'll need to modify this script to your specific system.

```
@ECHO Mounting Secure Drive (S:)
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 
SET x=0
FOR /F "usebackq" %%F IN (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\KeePass Password Safe 2\KPScript.exe" -c:GetEntryString C:\<LocationOfYourKeePassFile>\<keepassfilename>.kdbx -useraccount -ref-Title:<entrytitle> -Field:Password`) DO (
 SET Pass!x!=%%F
 set /a x+=1
)
"C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\truecrypt" /v \Device\Harddisk0\Partition4 /ls /s /q /p %Pass0% /b /h n /w
```

4) Lastly, set up a windows Task Scheduler to run the batch upon windows login.  Trigger should be "at log on" for the target user account. Action should be "Start a Program" with the target the full path to the batch script

Another feature I like about this approach is that I can save the encrypted file volume password elsewhere incase the windows account is corrupted or deleted.  I.e. I may lose access to the KeyPass file that is setup to use windows authentication but if I've saved the actual encrypted disk password somewhere else, I can still restore access to the encrypted volume.

Answer (score 0):

You change your KeePass database to use your Windows account as the master key, then install the `TrueCrypt` plugin for KeePass. You then have an entry in KeePass that contain the password for the `TrueCrypt` mount also registered with the `TrueCrypt` plugin.

With that in place, after you've logged in, open KeePass and select the entry and click **Ctrl + T** and you have the volume mounted in `TrueCrypt`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of unlocking a KeePass database with its master password automatically after the Windows log on. You can use the same database on other computer, because it will not be bound to your Windows user account. See this [Super User answer](https://superuser.com/questions/240657/make-keepass-database-accept-but-not-require-two-unlocking-methods/729804#729804) for details.